# Visual code debugger adapter immediately dies when trying to connect to vscode-hack debugger in local launch mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, hacklang

I am using the vscode-hack extension on visual code studio on macOS Big Sur. My `settings.json` includes following launch configuration:

```
"configurations": [
{
"name": "HHVM: Run Script",
"type": "hhvm",
"request": "launch",
"script": "${file}",
"hhvmPath": "/usr/local/bin/hhvm",
"hhvmArgs": ["--mode", "vsdebug", "--vsDebugPort", 8999],
"cwd":"${workspaceFolder}"
}
]
```

When I try to debug a Hack script in Visual code debugger, Visual code debugger adapter launches and immediately dies. I have verified launching hhvm with the same args from command line, and it works fine. I am following the instructions here `https://github.com/slackhq/vscode-hack/blob/master/docs/debugging.md`
Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: After trying around different combinations of configurations and vscode-hack extension, the following combination of the vscode-hack version and configuration works, so it appears this issue may have started with vscode-hack extension version 2.8.0.

This works: vscode-hack version: 2.7.1

configuration:
{
                "name": "HHVM: Run Script",
                "type": "hhvm",
                "request": "launch",
                "script": "${file}"
},

Comment: I have opened an issue on vscode-slack git repo: https://github.com/slackhq/vscode-hack/issues/125